# Routes for permutations of empty parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I would like to be able to call a route and account for all the possible permutations of empty parameters that could occur.

For example if param1 is not included:

```
match 'site//:param2/:param3'
```

Or only param3 is included, etc:

```
match 'site///:param3'
```

**Do I have to specify each case separately or is there a more elegant approach with only one route definition?**

Optional parameter will not work since for example :param1 called as '//' would become :param2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

[**Wildcards**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments)

Looks like a situation where you'd use `route wildcards`:

[image]

---

So perhaps you'd be able to do something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "*params, to: "controller#action"

#app/controllers/controller_controller.rb
class ControllerController < ApplicationController
    def action
       params = params[:params].split("/") #-> params[1] etc etc
    end
end
```

A bit hacky I guess, but if you can get it to work, you'll be in a much stronger position to elaborate on it & move it forward.

Comment: Will try this out. Not a bad idea. But, shouldn't "/*param1/*param2/" also work so that params can be parsed at the routing level? The docs hint that it should, or?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. Once the route is called with a parameter omitted, "//" the params variable that is received in the controller will simply leave it out. So p1/p2//p4 becomes p1/p2/p4